# Prove that $f$ is an increasing function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let $f$ be defined on the open interval $(a,b)$ and assume that for each $x\in(a,b)$ there exists a $1$-ball $B(x)$ in which $f$ is increasing. Can someone help me to prove that $f$ is increasing throughout $(a,b)$? Any answers will be much appreciated.

Comment: By "$1$-ball $B(x)$" do you mean an open interval centered at $x$ of radius $1$?

Comment: @CameronBuie yes it means that

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Every $[\alpha, \beta] \subset (a,b)$ is compact.

Comment: That's a leeetle on the vague side... Maybe you can provide a second hint in a spoiler screen? :)

Comment: @rschwieb, I read "1-ball" as "one dimensional ball"...

Comment: Since $[\alpha,\beta]$ is compact, if we take an open covering $\{B(t)\;|\; t\in[\alpha,\beta]\}$ of $[\alpha,\beta]$, there is a finite subcovering $\{B(t_k)\;|\; t_k\in[\alpha,\beta], k<n\}$.

Comment: Dear @njguliyev : I can't see how that addresses my comment. I just meant that the original hint is OK, it just seems a little too vague. A little more connection with the problem might make it a little more enlightening. Regards.

Comment: @rschwieb, I mean that after the OP explained "1-ball" as "a ball of radius 1" my hint seems too "heavy", it is possible to solve the problem more explicitly (as in the answer by Hagen von Eitzen).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x,y\in(a,b)$ with $x<y$. Pick $q\in(0,1)$
Let $n=\min\{k\in\mathbb N\mid x+qk\ge y\}$  and let $x_i=x+qi$ for $0\le i<k$. Then $n\ge 1$ and $$f(x)=f(x_0)<f(x_1)<\ldots <f(x_{n-1})< f(y).$$